# segfault with self-declared hash function

Tags: c++, hash, segmentation-fault, unordered-set

ChunkCorner.h

```
#pragma once
#include <filesystem>

#include <iostream>

class ChunkCorner
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    std::filesystem::path to_filename();
};

size_t hf(const ChunkCorner &chunk_corner);

bool eq(const ChunkCorner &c1, const ChunkCorner &c2);
```

ChunkCorner.cpp:
fwiw: The hf and eq function implementation is based on the C++ [Book](https://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) p. 917.

```
#include "ChunkCorner.h"

using namespace std;

size_t hf(const ChunkCorner &chunk_corner)
{
    return hash<int>()(chunk_corner.x) ^ hash<int>()(chunk_corner.y);
}

bool eq(const ChunkCorner &c1, const ChunkCorner &c2)
{
    return c1.x == c2.x && c1.y == c2.y;
}

[...]
```

In another bit of code I use the class as follows:

```
unordered_set<ChunkCorner, decltype(&hf), decltype(&eq)> chunks_to_load {};

ChunkCorner c {1,2};
chunks_to_load.insert(c);
```

On the insert call I get a segfault (determined using breakpoints).

I use VS Code and when I launch the program in debug mode, it jumps to the following bit on segfault in `hashtable_policy.h`:

```
      __hash_code
      _M_hash_code(const _Key& __k) const
      {
    static_assert(__is_invocable<const _H1&, const _Key&>{},
        "hash function must be invocable with an argument of key type");
    return _M_h1()(__k);
      }
```

I am new to C++ and have trouble understanding what the issue is and I am not sure how to proceed debugging...

Comment: Look at the exemples https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to You pass types of function pointers. When the pointers of these types are constructed, they point to nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the hash and equals functions to your constructor.  You've declared their type in the type arguments, which is going to be a pointer to function, but you haven't passed them in.  So they're likely being zero initalized, so nullptr.  Using them correctly should be done like this:

```
unordered_set<ChunkCorner, decltype(&hf), decltype(&eq)> chunks_to_load {16, hf, eq};
```

However, what I recommend is rewrite your Hash/Equals functions into function objects.  This way, the default operations will work properly.

```
struct MyHasher {
  size_t operator()(const ChunkCorner &chunk_corner) const
   {
     return hash<int>()(chunk_corner.x) ^ hash<int>()(chunk_corner.y);
   }
};

struct MyEq {
 bool operator()(const ChunkCorner &c1, const ChunkCorner &c2) const
  {
    return c1.x == c2.x && c1.y == c2.y;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can't you specialize `std::hast<ChunkCorner>` and implement `operator ==`?

Comment: Oh sure, you could. I suppose I just assumed there was a reason he didn't.  In particular, the fact that the filesystem path isn't part of the equals or hash check I suppose is why I made that assumption.

Comment: @DaveS Thanks, this works! What do you mean by "default operations work properly"?